# Databricks CLI to list or fetch the job run history of status

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I am looking for some options either using `databricks cli` or `Databricks notebook` code to get the list of the job execution.

with the `databricks job get --job-id <job_id> --profile=dbspace-1`, lists the metadata info of the job not the historic info of run.

For example, i am trying to get the list of job execution (refer the snapshot) and list out the Failed status. Since I am not aware of option to filter based on status using status in workspace UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of checking the documentation found below command lists the data i need

```
databricks runs list --job-id <job=id> --profile=dbworkspace-1
```

can use `limit` option to grab more than 20 records.